# Check if item in list

Tags: python, list

I have a function like this:

```
def checks(a,b):
    for item in a:
        if b[1] == item[1]:
           return True
        else:
           return False
```

I want to check if the second value of b is in the second value of item in a such as:

```
checks(['5v','7y'],'6y')
>>> True
```

But the code I have right now will return `False` because I believe it's comparing `'6y'` with `'5v'`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re returning `True` at the right spot, but if the first item doesn‘t match, the function returns `False` immediately instead of continuing with the loop. Just move the `return False` to the end of the function, outside of the loop:

```
def checks(a,b):
    for item in a:
        if b[1] == item[1]:
           return True

    return False
```

`True` will be returned if an item is matched and `False` will be returned if the loop finishes without a match.

Anyways, that explains why your code wasn’t working, but use `any` as suggested by others to be Pythonic. =)

Comment: this challenge feels like it requires more thought.  rather than returning true on a match, it may make more sense to use a 'flag' variable checking for errors during the loop, and returning the final result.

Answer (score 2):

This can be expressed in a simpler way:

```
def checks(a, b):
    return any(b[1] == item[1] for item in a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `any()` here:

```
def checks(a,b):
    return any (b[1] == item[1] for item in a)

>>> checks(['5v','7y'],'6y')
True
>>> checks(['5v','7z'],'6y')
False
```

Help on `any`:

```
>>> print any.__doc__
any(iterable) -> bool

Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
If the iterable is empty, return False.
```

Comment: IMO, if OP is having trouble with a basic `for` loop, I don't think `any` with a generator is going to make things easier to understand.